# VS2010, C#, passing parameter bulk into threads, speed issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I have the code below where it update the data within listview, I was trying to pass parameter into main code which update the listview table.

I have external code that can send burst data stream and it shown same value on the list.

Below is based on anonymous method which work but earlier data get overwritten.

The listview is too slow which slow down main program (not listed here) the burst data goes to this code and use separate thread to handle the display (about 20 set). The burst data is about 20 set of dataTX array, etc.

I'm open for suggestion how to fix this.

==========================================================================

```
    public void LIN_Request_Add_Message(bool isCRCIncluded)           // This Add new line for request based message.
    {
        byte[] dataTX = new byte[10];
        dataTX = myLinTools.LinArrayTXArray();
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

        this.ReqAddMessageThread = new Thread(delegate() { ReqAddMessageThreadProc(isCRCIncluded, dataTX, d); });          //anonymous method
        this.ReqAddMessageThread.Start();
    }
    #endregion

    private void ReqAddMessageThreadProc(bool isCRCIncluded, byte[] dataTX, DateTime d)
    {
        if (this.OutputView.InvokeRequired)
        {
            test1Callback del = new test1Callback(ReqAddMessageThreadProc);
            this.Invoke(del, new object[] { isCRCIncluded, dataTX,d });
            return;
        }

        if (this.Visible == true)
        {
            SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);
        }

        int length = myLinTools.LINDataLength;
        int pCRC = 0;
        elem = new ListViewItem(m_Item.ToString());

        elem.SubItems.Add(d.Date.ToShortDateString());
        elem.SubItems.Add(d.ToShortTimeString() + ":" + d.Second.ToString());
        elem.SubItems.Add("");
        for (int i = 0; i < length + 1; i++)
        {
            elem.SubItems.Add(dataTX[i].ToString("X2"));
            pCRC = i;
        }
        for (int i = length; i < 8; i++)
        {
            elem.SubItems.Add("  ");  // fill gaps
        }
        if (isCRCIncluded == true)      // Does the message contains processed CRC data?
        {
            elem.SubItems.Add(dataTX[pCRC + 1].ToString("X2"));
        }
        else                            // No, then make one for display only!!
        {
            Byte CRC = myLinTools.CRC_Processor(false);
            elem.SubItems.Add(CRC.ToString("X2"));
        }
        this.OutputView.Items.Add(elem);
        this.OutputView.EnsureVisible(m_Item);
        if (myLinTools.IsRequestResponse == true)       // Request Message Only
        {
            if (this.Visible == true)                   // Is form open?
            {
                SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
        m_Item++;
    }
```

=================================================================================

Thanks KazR, I modified the code which worked fine, however it slow down the other high level program (call it main program), that making data transfer to this program that display data. One of the requirement that the main program stream the data without delay or pause cause by listview in this display program. That why I'm looking for way to use thread, so it release the control back to main program and thus operates faster, but however there is issue in keep data from being over-written by next thread, since listview is slow. Perhaps I should consider a buffer, which update only when there is no activity in main program.

I do not wish to use virtual, I'm open for alternative suggestion.

==================================================================================

```
delegate void ReqAddMessageTCallback(bool isCRCIncluded, byte[] dataTX, DateTime d);
#region//==================================================LIN_Request_Add_Message
public void LIN_Request_Add_Message(bool isCRCIncluded)           // This Add new line for request based message.
{
    byte[] dataTX = new byte[10];
    dataTX = myLinTools.LinArrayTXArray();
    DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
    ReqAddMessageThreadProc(isCRCIncluded, dataTX, d);

}
#endregion

#region//==================================================ReqAddMessageThreadProc
private void ReqAddMessageThreadProc(bool isCRCIncluded, byte[] dataTX, DateTime d)
{
    if (this.OutputView.InvokeRequired)
    {
        ReqAddMessageTCallback del = new ReqAddMessageTCallback(ReqAddMessageThreadProc);
        this.BeginInvoke(del, new object[] { isCRCIncluded, dataTX, d });
        return;
    }

    if (this.Visible == true)
    {
        SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);
    }

    int length = myLinTools.LINDataLength;
    int pCRC = 0;
    elem = new ListViewItem(m_Item.ToString());
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new byte array and then effectively throwing it away? Why not just use `byte[] dataTX = myLinTools.LinArrayTXArray();`?

Comment: Thank Mark, I getting hang of this now!

Comment: Jon, yes you're right, I better review the code.

Answer (score 1):

From your code example it appears that you're creating a new Thread object each time you receive data and all this thread is doing is calling the ReqAddMessageThreadProc method. Assuming that calls to LIN_Request_Add_Message are not being made in the main UI thread, you could try removing the Thread creation & start calls, replace them with a direct call the ReqAddMessageThreadProc and use BeginInvoke rather than Invoke.

e.g.

```
public void LIN_Request_Add_Message(bool isCRCIncluded)           // This Add new line for request based message.
{
    byte[] dataTX = new byte[10];
    dataTX = myLinTools.LinArrayTXArray();
    DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

    ReqAddMessageThreadProc(isCRCIncluded, dataTX, d);

}
#endregion

private void ReqAddMessageThreadProc(bool isCRCIncluded, byte[] dataTX, DateTime d)
{
    if (this.OutputView.InvokeRequired)
    {
        test1Callback del = new test1Callback(ReqAddMessageThreadProc);
        this.BeginInvoke(del, new object[] { isCRCIncluded, dataTX,d });
        return;
    }
```

etc...

The BeginInvoke call is the async version of Invoke, this should negate the need to use separate new Thread objects each time you receive new data.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your ListView virtual. Then you can operate at full speed with your threads and the listview will display only the items which are currently visible. If you do append things to the ListView and not force to make it visible every time something is added you can let the user decide when he does want to scroll down. He does see when things are appended because the scrollbar is becoming smaller and smaller while items are added.

This way you can display millions of entries without any issues and you will get rid of ivoking, redrawing, refreshing the listview via SendMessage. Here is a [virtual list view sample](http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2010/06/21/140545.aspx) how you can change it.

By doing so your code will become simpler and faster because you do not mix background data processing with UI stuff. E.g. sorting can be done at raw data array level without doing anything in the UI except to trigger it.